# spring boot 3 app finished work after run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logging, spring-security

I am migrating my app to spring boot 3 from spring boot 2.7.9 (and of course spring security etc.). After I run my application I don' t see any logs and app finished with exit code 0.
I try to run my application after every change of dependency in pom.xml and still works, but when I change spring-boot version to 3.1.1 app behaves like the screen shows.
[App behavior after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAnFw.png)

Thanks for any help.

I expect to see logs or working app

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.